# Show timer in salesforce visualforce page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

How to show timer in visualforce page ? It should be decrement from the current system time. This is my requirement. If anyone knows update here.

Answer (score 0):

You can get current system time (Of local machine) in JavaScript for example see [here](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptdate.php) .
You can get Salesforce org system time [with](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm)